# Best e-shop (or module for Joomla or Drupal) for groceries calatog

Tags: gratis, cms, ecommerce

I am looking for some e-shop system (and plugins, if needed).

I'd like to do a website with these features:

- E-shop-like interface - each food has own page with info, food can be split into categories, each category can be listed. Pretty much classic e-shop. But - I won't be selling anything, just want to provide info about the products.
- Each product can be ranked (1-5 or 1-10) and products in each category can be listed by best score.
- People may comment on products (but only one comment per person, if that's possible).
- And it would be great if ranking and commenting were accessible just by authentization via Facebook.

I am not skilled in web technologies, but I know general IT stuff, so the simpler the creation and administration would be, the better. If possible, I'd like to use free software.